# CSS * overriding class style

Tags: html, css

I'm having some difficulty with applying CSS. I have a text color specified in a global external style sheet, which uses * to apply the color. I'm now trying to override this for one specific class. I've tried setting the text color for the class within the header of the document (which if I'm correct should override the external sheet?), however the color will not change.

Google chrome inspector shows me that * is still dominating the class specification. Any ideas?

My external style sheet looks like this:

```
* {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666;
 }
```

and my header style looks like this:

```
.error-list {
   color: red !important;
}
```

Its worth mentioning that I've tried it with and without the !important.

Comment: Show us the CSS you have

Comment: I've editing my question to show the CSS.

Comment: What color does the `error-list` has? ... gray as in #666 ... and you do have a typo where you missed `:` in `color #666`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your CSS rule more specific. For example if your .error-list is made of li tags. Change your CSS rule to .error-list li to make it more specific.

Comment: Try making you class more specific. For example if you r .error-list is made of li tags, then use .error-list li as you CSS rule. That may help.

Comment: That worked!! If you post it as an answer I will mark it as resolved. Thank you!!

Comment: Edited my current answer to match the answer in the comments. Thanks you and you are welcome.

Comment: Here's a nice resource about CSS specificity: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to which has higher [*specificity*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

In below sample the `span` and the `error-list` rule has higher specificity than `*`, but the `div.error-list` has even higher than the `error-list`, so even if the `error-list` is placed after in the CSS, the highest wins (as with the first `div` in below sample).

To override

```css
* {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666;
}

span {
  color: red;
}

div.error-list {
   color: blue;
}

.error-list {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>Hey, I'm red</span>

<div class="error-list">Hey, I'm <strike>red too</strike> blue</div>

<div class="error-list">Hey, I'm blue</div>
```

To override a higher specificity, one can use `!important`, below done on the 2  `error-list` (compare result with the first sample above).

```css
* {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666;
}

span {
  color: red;
}

div.error-list {
   color: blue;
}

.error-list {
   color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<span>Hey, I'm red</span>

<div class="error-list">Hey, I'm <strike>red too</strike> blue</div>

<div class="error-list">Hey, I'm blue</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect it, do you see the class you created? Maybe its not there at all.

Its hard to tell without the code but anyway `!important` can override the global class.
Also inline css would override it but since you need to reuse it as a class this is not recommended

try this:

```
element[style] { /*don't change the style*/
   color: red!important;
}
```

Comment: Upon inspection I do see the class there fine. Its shows the text color as being crossed through in the class. My updated answer includes the CSS and I've tried !important, which unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Please send url and I would try fixing it.

Comment: I cannot send the URL as the site is being run locally.